# Внезапный редикрет

Tags: python, http, redirect, django-rest-framework

Использую библиотеку simplejwt для авторизации на сайте. Протестировал на локальной машине всё ок, клонировал проект на сервак и при авторизации начали странные редиректы (см. скрин).

```
IP:ADDRESS [21/Sep/2022:13:38:37 +0300] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "insomnia/2022.5.1"
IP:ADDRESS [21/Sep/2022:13:38:37 +0300] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 405 40 "-" "insomnia/2022.5.1"
```

Использовал `TokenObtainPairView` из `rest_framework_simplejwt.views`, так сказать из коробки.

```
] + [ # Работа с токенами
    path('login/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

Версии модулей:

```
asgiref==3.5.2
Django==3.2.15
djangorestframework==3.13.1
djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.2.0
PyJWT==2.5.0
pytz==2022.2.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
typing_extensions==4.3.0
```

На данном сервере стоит ещё одно приложение с такой же авторизацией, но при авторизации такой проблемы не наблюдается

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Извиняюсь, сейчас исправлюсь

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была вот в чём
Все запросы я отправлял на HTTP, но nginx делал редирект на HTTPS и из-за этого происходила ошибка.